# Scrolling animation is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a test website where the use clicks an anchor element that takes them to the next section of the page. I cant figure out why I my animation is not showing when the user clicks on the on the anchor.

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 2000);
});
```

});

```
    <head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rokkitt" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="section00" class="siteName selector">Travel More</h1>
    <h2 class="downPage"><a href="#section01" class="down1">&#x02228;</a></h2>
  </header>



  <section id="section01" class="content selector"><a href="#section02" class="down1">Second</a></section>



  <section id="section02" class="content selector">
    <a class="down1" href="#section03">Third</a>
</section>


<section id="section03" class="content selector">
    <a class="down1" href="#section00">Last</a>
</section>




  <footer><p>Travel More 2016</p></footer>
</body>
```

[This is a link to the code (codepen)](http://codepen.io/Stakeley/pen/YpEGNR)

Comment: Can you provide html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$('a[href*=#]')` to this `$('a[href^="#"]')`. You were using the wrong syntax

Answer (score 1):

Look at the console logs. There is:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]
```

Try use:

```
$('a[href^="#"]')
```